# SSL Cert Vendor Change

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, tomcat6, jks

I am trying to prepare for the switch in the SSL certificate vendors.

For the the SSL validation, Our Tomcat web application uses a JKS file created from a DigiCert certificate ( *.cer files). Our company is now switching to VeriSign next week. Since they have already provided the new *.cer files, can I simply add the new cert ( using keytool) to the existing JKS so that it works for both certificates. I am trying to avoid any downtime during the switch and prepare the server beforehand?

Any helps will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You must install the certificate onto the same keystore you created the CSR from as the private key resides there. Otherwise it will not work. Please reference the article below on instructions on how to import into a tomcat server:

https://knowledge.verisign.com/support/ssl-certificates-support/index?page=content&id=AR234&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US&searchid=1369174910074